# If $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ holds for $0<z<1$, then also for $0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

In [Special Functions p. 10](https://books.google.de/books?id=kGshpCa3eYwC&lpg=PP1&hl=da&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false), it has proven that
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)},$$
for $0<z<1$. Then it says that this equality implies for $0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1$.

I do not understand this implication. How do we know that it's true in the imaginary part?

Comment: Because of the identity theorem. It holds for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ by that. (And if you interpret it as an identity of meromorphic functions, you don't need to exclude $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I didn't believe that it would work, if $\operatorname{Im}(z)\neq 0$. I tried to read about the identity theorem, but there are different versions of it. Just want to be sure; Let $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$. Define $f,g:A\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)$ and $g(z)=\pi/\sin(\pi z)$. Since they are analytical and $f|_{A\cap \mathbb{R}}=g|_{A\cap \mathbb{R}}$, it follows from Identity theorem that $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in A$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, since $A$ is connected, and $A\cap \mathbb{R}$ has a limit point in $A$. You can take $A = \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, and the connectedness of this open set together with the fact that $(0,1)$ has a limit point in it gives you the identity on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I am trying to understand the extension of the domain. Both sides are holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, so it follows from the identity theorem, that it holds for $\Re z \in (0,1)$. Does this imply that it also holds for $\Re z =0,1$ with $z\neq 0,1$? If yes, why?

Comment: $U:=\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is connected, and hence the identity theorem says that two functions that are holomorphic on $U$ and agree on some set that has an accumulation point in $U$ actually agree on all of $U$. There is no need to consider the intermediate strip $A=\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:0<\operatorname{Re} z<1\}$ at all, if you know that $\Gamma$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Probably that strip appears because $\Gamma$ was defined by an integral that only converges for $\operatorname{Re} z>0$, e.g. $$\Gamma(z) := \int_0^{+\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt.$$

Comment: Then you only know that $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)$ is defined on the strip $A$, and you can as the first step only apply the identity theorem to $A$. But as soon as you know that $\Gamma$ is defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (or can be analytically continued to that set), the connectedness of $U$ and the fact that $(0,1)$ has an accumulation point in $U$ [every point of that interval is an accumulation point] directly gives you the identity on all of $U$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry for the late answer. It seems I have misunderstood the theorem. You explained the way I haven't thought before, thanks. If you could copy your comments to an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the identity theorem for holomorphic functions:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and connected, and $f, g \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. If the set $E := \{ z \in U : f(z) = g(z)\}$ has an accumulation point in $U$, then $E = U$.

*Remark:* It is essential that the set $E$ has an accumulation point **in $U$**. If $E$ only has accumulation points at the boundary of $U$, then the conclusion need not hold.

Since every point of the interval $I = (0,1)$ is an accumulation point of $I$, the identity

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi z)}\tag{1}$$

for $z \in I$ extends to every connected open set $U$ with $I \subset U$ (actually, $I \cap U \neq \varnothing$ suffices) on which both sides of $(1)$ are holomorphic functions by the identity theorem.

With the integral representation

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{+\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t}\,dt,\tag{2}$$

which is valid for $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$, one gets the holomorphic function $z \mapsto \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1 - z)$ on the strip $A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \operatorname{Re} z < 1\}$. Clearly $z \mapsto \dfrac{\pi}{\sin (\pi z)}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z} \supset A$, and $A$ is connected, so this yields $(1)$ for all $z \in A$.

If one has a representation of the $\Gamma$-function valid for $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{ -n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, one sees that $z \mapsto \Gamma(z) \Gamma(1 - z)$ is in fact holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, and hence the identity $(1)$ holds on the connected open set $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$.